# Calculating Median/Quantile of Rasterstack and converting Results to Data Frame in R

Tags: r, raster-conversion, data-frame, rasterstack

I have a Raster Stack with 32 Raster Layers. What I want to do is to calculate the median for each Raster and also the 0.25 and 0.75 quantiles. Then I want to convert the results into a dataframe.

For the median I have allready found a quite simple solution:

```
#calculate median and convert to dataframe

median.df <- data.frame(cellStats(r_stack, "median"))
```

The Problem is, that I can´t do the same with the quantiles, since cellStats cant calculate that.

My best approach with the quantiles so far was:

```
quant <- calc(r_stack, fun = function(x) 
          {quantile(x,probs = c(.25,.75),na.rm=TRUE)} )

quant.df <- as.data.frame(quant)
```

But the dataframe has 16644 rows instead of the expected 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply a function to `cellStats` - here on a 5 layer example:

```
> cellStats(r_stack, function(s,...){quantile(s,probs=c(.25,.75))})
      layer.1   layer.2   layer.3   layer.4   layer.5
25% 0.3613589 0.2072302 0.3314491 0.3160375 0.1740109
75% 0.8063743 0.8571872 0.8297163 0.6712669 0.7010024
```

that's a matrix but save that as `m` and a quick flip to a dataframe is easy enough:

```
> data.frame(t(m))
             X25.      X75.
layer.1 0.3613589 0.8063743
layer.2 0.2072302 0.8571872
layer.3 0.3314491 0.8297163
layer.4 0.3160375 0.6712669
layer.5 0.1740109 0.7010024
```

quick check, this should match the third row:

```
> quantile(r_stack[[3]],probs=c(.25,.75))
      25%       75% 
0.3314491 0.8297163
```

Comment: Thank you very much Spacedman! The code works for me after I added na.rm=TRUE in the quantile function.